# How to start ssh with wt.exe and keep terminal colors

Tags: powershell, windows-terminal, starship

I have this shortcut

`C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe --window 0 -p "Windows Powershell" C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe -noExit -Command "ssh webdev"`

It works fine but the terminal opened doesn't have colors.

This is regular terminal:

[image]

This is the shortcut:

[image]

A video of me opening an ssh connection in different ways.

https://files.catbox.moe/vskxx0.webm

Shortcut 1: `"C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -Command "ssh webdev"`

Shortcut 2: `wt.exe "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -Command "ssh webdev"`

I'd like to use wt.exe because I like being able to easily open a new tab.

### Update

I found in `C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminal_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json` that the colorScheme used is the default one 'Solarized Dark' instead of the 'Windows PowerShell 7' profile's 'One Half Dark'.

Even if specified in the shortcut

`C:\Users\David\AppData\Local\Microsoft\WindowsApps\wt.exe -p "Windows Powershell 7"  "C:\Program Files\PowerShell\7\pwsh.exe" -Command "ssh webdev"`

```json
{
    "$help": "https://aka.ms/terminal-documentation",
    "$schema": "https://aka.ms/terminal-profiles-schema",
    "actions": 
    [
        {
            "command": "find",
            "keys": "ctrl+shift+f"
        },
        {
            "command": "paste",
            "keys": "ctrl+v"
        },
        {
            "command": 
            {
                "action": "copy",
                "singleLine": false
            },
            "keys": "ctrl+c"
        },
        {
            "command": 
            {
                "action": "splitPane",
                "split": "auto",
                "splitMode": "duplicate"
            },
            "keys": "alt+shift+d"
        }
    ],
    "copyFormatting": "none",
    "copyOnSelect": false,
    "defaultProfile": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
    "profiles": 
    {
        "defaults": 
        {
            "colorScheme": "Solarized Dark",
            "font": 
            {
                "face": "FiraCode Nerd Font Mono"
            }
        },
        "list": 
        [
            {
                "colorScheme": "One Half Dark",
                "commandline": "C:\\Program Files\\PowerShell\\7\\pwsh.exe",
                "guid": "{61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "Windows PowerShell 7"
            },
            {
                "guid": "{0caa0dad-35be-5f56-a8ff-afceeeaa6101}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "S\u00edmbolo del sistema"
            },
            {
                "guid": "{c6eaf9f4-32a7-5fdc-b5cf-066e8a4b1e40}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "Ubuntu-18.04",
                "source": "Windows.Terminal.Wsl"
            },
            {
                "guid": "{b453ae62-4e3d-5e58-b989-0a998ec441b8}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "Azure Cloud Shell",
                "source": "Windows.Terminal.Azure"
            },
            {
                "guid": "{cc1103f1-07a6-5722-a92c-731a1a864d7f}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "Developer Command Prompt for VS 2022",
                "source": "Windows.Terminal.VisualStudio"
            },
            {
                "guid": "{6501f08f-1c83-5423-afd5-5e1b828bff9a}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "Developer PowerShell for VS 2022",
                "source": "Windows.Terminal.VisualStudio"
            },
            {
                "guid": "{574e775e-4f2a-5b96-ac1e-a2962a402336}",
                "hidden": false,
                "name": "PowerShell",
                "source": "Windows.Terminal.PowershellCore"
            }
        ]
    },
    "schemes": 
    [
        {
            "background": "#0C0C0C",
            "black": "#0C0C0C",
            "blue": "#0037DA",
            "brightBlack": "#767676",
            "brightBlue": "#3B78FF",
            "brightCyan": "#61D6D6",
            "brightGreen": "#16C60C",
            "brightPurple": "#B4009E",
            "brightRed": "#E74856",
            "brightWhite": "#F2F2F2",
            "brightYellow": "#F9F1A5",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#3A96DD",
            "foreground": "#CCCCCC",
            "green": "#13A10E",
            "name": "Campbell",
            "purple": "#881798",
            "red": "#C50F1F",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#CCCCCC",
            "yellow": "#C19C00"
        },
        {
            "background": "#012456",
            "black": "#0C0C0C",
            "blue": "#0037DA",
            "brightBlack": "#767676",
            "brightBlue": "#3B78FF",
            "brightCyan": "#61D6D6",
            "brightGreen": "#16C60C",
            "brightPurple": "#B4009E",
            "brightRed": "#E74856",
            "brightWhite": "#F2F2F2",
            "brightYellow": "#F9F1A5",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#3A96DD",
            "foreground": "#CCCCCC",
            "green": "#13A10E",
            "name": "Campbell Powershell",
            "purple": "#881798",
            "red": "#C50F1F",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#CCCCCC",
            "yellow": "#C19C00"
        },
        {
            "background": "#282C34",
            "black": "#282C34",
            "blue": "#61AFEF",
            "brightBlack": "#5A6374",
            "brightBlue": "#61AFEF",
            "brightCyan": "#56B6C2",
            "brightGreen": "#98C379",
            "brightPurple": "#C678DD",
            "brightRed": "#E06C75",
            "brightWhite": "#DCDFE4",
            "brightYellow": "#E5C07B",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#56B6C2",
            "foreground": "#DCDFE4",
            "green": "#98C379",
            "name": "One Half Dark",
            "purple": "#C678DD",
            "red": "#E06C75",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#DCDFE4",
            "yellow": "#E5C07B"
        },
        {
            "background": "#FAFAFA",
            "black": "#383A42",
            "blue": "#0184BC",
            "brightBlack": "#4F525D",
            "brightBlue": "#61AFEF",
            "brightCyan": "#56B5C1",
            "brightGreen": "#98C379",
            "brightPurple": "#C577DD",
            "brightRed": "#DF6C75",
            "brightWhite": "#FFFFFF",
            "brightYellow": "#E4C07A",
            "cursorColor": "#4F525D",
            "cyan": "#0997B3",
            "foreground": "#383A42",
            "green": "#50A14F",
            "name": "One Half Light",
            "purple": "#A626A4",
            "red": "#E45649",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#FAFAFA",
            "yellow": "#C18301"
        },
        {
            "background": "#002B36",
            "black": "#002B36",
            "blue": "#268BD2",
            "brightBlack": "#073642",
            "brightBlue": "#839496",
            "brightCyan": "#93A1A1",
            "brightGreen": "#586E75",
            "brightPurple": "#6C71C4",
            "brightRed": "#CB4B16",
            "brightWhite": "#FDF6E3",
            "brightYellow": "#657B83",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#2AA198",
            "foreground": "#839496",
            "green": "#859900",
            "name": "Solarized Dark",
            "purple": "#D33682",
            "red": "#DC322F",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#EEE8D5",
            "yellow": "#B58900"
        },
        {
            "background": "#FDF6E3",
            "black": "#002B36",
            "blue": "#268BD2",
            "brightBlack": "#073642",
            "brightBlue": "#839496",
            "brightCyan": "#93A1A1",
            "brightGreen": "#586E75",
            "brightPurple": "#6C71C4",
            "brightRed": "#CB4B16",
            "brightWhite": "#FDF6E3",
            "brightYellow": "#657B83",
            "cursorColor": "#002B36",
            "cyan": "#2AA198",
            "foreground": "#657B83",
            "green": "#859900",
            "name": "Solarized Light",
            "purple": "#D33682",
            "red": "#DC322F",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#EEE8D5",
            "yellow": "#B58900"
        },
        {
            "background": "#000000",
            "black": "#000000",
            "blue": "#3465A4",
            "brightBlack": "#555753",
            "brightBlue": "#729FCF",
            "brightCyan": "#34E2E2",
            "brightGreen": "#8AE234",
            "brightPurple": "#AD7FA8",
            "brightRed": "#EF2929",
            "brightWhite": "#EEEEEC",
            "brightYellow": "#FCE94F",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#06989A",
            "foreground": "#D3D7CF",
            "green": "#4E9A06",
            "name": "Tango Dark",
            "purple": "#75507B",
            "red": "#CC0000",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#D3D7CF",
            "yellow": "#C4A000"
        },
        {
            "background": "#FFFFFF",
            "black": "#000000",
            "blue": "#3465A4",
            "brightBlack": "#555753",
            "brightBlue": "#729FCF",
            "brightCyan": "#34E2E2",
            "brightGreen": "#8AE234",
            "brightPurple": "#AD7FA8",
            "brightRed": "#EF2929",
            "brightWhite": "#EEEEEC",
            "brightYellow": "#FCE94F",
            "cursorColor": "#000000",
            "cyan": "#06989A",
            "foreground": "#555753",
            "green": "#4E9A06",
            "name": "Tango Light",
            "purple": "#75507B",
            "red": "#CC0000",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#D3D7CF",
            "yellow": "#C4A000"
        },
        {
            "background": "#000000",
            "black": "#000000",
            "blue": "#000080",
            "brightBlack": "#808080",
            "brightBlue": "#0000FF",
            "brightCyan": "#00FFFF",
            "brightGreen": "#00FF00",
            "brightPurple": "#FF00FF",
            "brightRed": "#FF0000",
            "brightWhite": "#FFFFFF",
            "brightYellow": "#FFFF00",
            "cursorColor": "#FFFFFF",
            "cyan": "#008080",
            "foreground": "#C0C0C0",
            "green": "#008000",
            "name": "Vintage",
            "purple": "#800080",
            "red": "#800000",
            "selectionBackground": "#FFFFFF",
            "white": "#C0C0C0",
            "yellow": "#808000"
        }
    ]
}
```

### Fixed

`-p "Windows Powershell 7"`
SHOULD HAVE BEEN
`-p "Windows PowerShell 7"`

Comment: But opening the terminal, and then doing ssh works fine, https://i.imgur.com/6AHak0Y.png

Comment: It start to get unclear..... When is what supposed to happen? Where is your "starship customization" configured?  Which system is `webdev` (local or remote?)      Some of the [details](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask#:~:text=Pretend%20you%27re%20talking%20to%20a%20busy%20colleague%20and%20have%20to%20sum%20up%20your%20entire%20question%20in%20one%20sentence%3A%20what%20details%20can%20you%20include%20that%20will%20help%20someone%20identify%20and%20solve%20your%20problem%3F) seems to be missing.

Comment: Added more info, I realize I won't get starship since it's not on the tyarget machine, an Ubuntu VM.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To provide the solution in the form of an answer:

- For **`wt.exe`**, [Windows Terminal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/)'s [CLI](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/terminal/command-line-arguments) to recognize a **`-p` argument** (profile name) if **must match the name of a defined profile *in full, case-exactly***;<sup>[1]</sup>

  - If there is ***no* exact match**, Windows Terminal **quietly falls back to the *default* profile** (whatever its name is).
  - You may alternatively pass a profile's *GUID* (which you can glean from the `settings.json` file) to `-p` (the same fallback logic applies).
- Because your `-p` argument differed in case from the actual profile name - `p "Windows Powershell 7"` (note the lowercase `s` in `Powershell`) vs. `-p "Windows PowerShell 7"` - your *default* profile was used instead.

  - As an aside: There is no such thing as *Windows PowerShell 7*: there's *Windows PowerShell*, the legacy edition whose latest and *last* version is 5.1, and there is *PowerShell (Core)* (possibly prefixed with *Microsoft*, but NOT *Windows*), the modern, cross-platform edition that is currently at v7.x (and whose first version was v6.0).

Fixing the case mismatch solved your problem.

---

<sup>[1] It is (unfortunately) also possible to (accidentally) create multiple profiles *with the exact same name* (but different GUIDs), in which case the *first* one defined is the effective one (based on the order shown in the Settings GUI).

By contrast, duplicate profile GUIDs (which are automatically created and assigned when you use the Settings GUI) *are* detected and result in an error message.</sup>

Answer (score 1):

You might have more than one profile named "Windows Powershell".

To check that, here's how to get a list of the profiles involed:

```
$myJSON = Get-Content $myJSON = Get-Content "$env:LOCALAPPDATA\Packages\Microsoft.WindowsTerminalPreview_8wekyb3d8bbwe\LocalState\settings.json" -Raw | ConvertFrom-Json
$myJSON.profiles.list |  Where name -match "Windows Powershell"
```

On my system this only gives one profile:

```
colorScheme : Campbell Powershell
commandline : %SystemRoot%\System32\WindowsPowerShell\v1.0\powershell.exe
guid        : {61c54bbd-c2c6-5271-96e7-009a87ff44bf}
hidden      : False
name        : Windows PowerShell
```

I think (guess) multiple profiles might be the cause of your problem ?

Comment: Good point. The screen recording shows a profile name of `Windows PowerShell 7` (which, as an aside, is a contradiction in terms). So perhaps all that it takes is to replace `-p 'Windows PowerShell'` with ``-p 'Windows PowerShell 7'``. On a general note, `wt.exe` only recognizes a `-p` argument (profile name) if it matches the name of a defined profile _in full, case-exactly_ and otherwise quietly falls back to the _default_ profile.

Comment: @mklement0 it was the lowercase s